# Need a regular expression to match letter followed by number or capital

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that can replace the lowercase letter `n` with a newline, but only when it is followed by a digit `0-9` or a capital letter.

For example, the string:
`Company Buildingn100 Prospect Way`

Should convert into:
`Company Building

 100 Prospect Way`

I'm trying to sanitize this data in PHP, so the resulting expression needs to be compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
n(?=[\dA-Z])
```

In PHP ([working example](http://ideone.com/QPWEH)):

```
$str = preg_replace("/n(?=[\dA-Z])/", "\n", $str);
```

`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead - it checks what's after the `n` we matched, but doesn't match it, so the next character isn't replaced.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = preg_replace("/n(?=[\dA-Z])/", "\n", $subject);
```

will do this if by capital letter you mean ASCII letters.

```
$result = preg_replace("/n(?=[\d\p{Lu}])/u", "\n", $subject);
```

if you're using Unicode.

Comment: @BoltClock: I had RegexBuddy generate this code snippet (I don't know PHP); could you elaborate what's wrong with single quotes?

Comment: PHP will not understand escape characters in single quotes, only in double quotes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single . Sample code: http://ideone.com/8Pfhy (note it prints `\\n`, and not a new line as it will with `"\n"`). By the way, I've found this useful site for PHP regexes: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm (I don't know any PHP either, but you catch stuff with time `:)`)