# Regex help, words that contain numbers without a space

Tags: c#, regex

I have been trying for hours now to figure out this regex and it will not work correctly.

What i need is one that will match the following:
I need it to match IF any word in the entire description is a character followed by a number, **without a space**

for example:

MC15 this is a test description - **MATCH**

MC 15 this is another description - **NO MATCH**

another test MC55 description - **MATCH**

another test MC 55 description - **NO MATCH**

i greatly appreciate any help!
thanks for your time!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734438/need-a-regular-expression-to-match-letter-followed-by-number-or-capital and download a regex cheatsheet: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @JoeTuskan no need for the character class around `\d`, it's an atom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<aMatch>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)`

This matches any a-z or A-Z character one or more times followed by any number 0-9 one or more times, no spaces or any other character allowed to separate them

Comment: this ended up doing exactly what i needed, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Can you use "find" instead of "match"?  (I.E., the regular expression method you call on your pattern - in order to search for a substring instead of matching against the entire input?)  If so, this will do nicely:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\d+)
```

Otherwise, it can be expanded to work with "match", using something like:

```
\b*([a-zA-Z]+\d+)\b*
```

Comment: +1 for `find()`, and -Inf for C# for repeating the same error as Java wrt the naming of its regex methods!

Comment: @fge - thanks, but I actually made some Java-based assumptions in regards to the answer, which work the same as JavaScript and most other languages that I'm familiar with.  I'm still searching to find the exact .Net-equivalent calls, as it's been a while...

Answer (score 0):

In perl, a regexp like `/[a-zA-Z]+\d+/` would work:

- `[a-zA-Z]` denotes **any** letter
- `\d` denotes any decimal
- the `+` after each character class says it has to be present one or more times